# Looking for a JavaScript WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg, emoticons

I'm looking for a light-weight WYSIWYG JavaScript editor I can put on my website that supports emoticons.

Comment: You're hardly the first. You just have spent no effort whatsoever looking.

Comment: How did you post your question if this website is offline? 0_o

Comment: Writing a text editor that does even a *tiny* bit more than the built-in `<textarea>` is so hard that nobody wants to do it unless they're adding *huge* amounts of functionality.

Comment: minitech: Oh you are incorrect. I was looking a lot
Jeremy Heiler: I mean WDE Editor's website is offline.

Comment: @PatlaDJ: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=wysiwyg+editor . TinyMCE is the second non-ad result.

Comment: Well you've totally changed my question. Now do you expect me to do?

Comment: @PatlaDJ: I tried to clarify the question without changing the original meaning.  If I still got it wrong, please feel free to change it back to the way you had it.

Comment: @PatlaDJ, how is the question "totally changed"? You wanted a javascript editor that supported emoticons, right? What else were you asking?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), which has a virtual cornucopia of options, including emoticons (smilies), bold, underline, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). It's a full featured, highly customizable WYSIWYG editor that supports everything you ever need.